# Disable manual sliding in Slick Slider

Tags: carousel, slick.js

I want to Disable manual sliding in Slick Slider and want the controls (next and prev) only to trigger the prev and next functionality.

I want to Disable manual sliding in Slick Slider and want the controls (next and prev) only to trigger the prev and next functionality.

My config looks like:

```
$('.slick', '.vertical-slider').slick({
  vertical: true,
  verticalSwiping: true,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  prevArrow: false,
  nextArrow: false,
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 500,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000,
  pauseOnHover: false,
  draggable: false,
  prevArrow: "<img class='a-left control-c prev slick-prev' width='10px' src='./public/images/left-carousel-arrow.svg'>",
  nextArrow: "<img class='a-right control-c next slick-next' width='10px' src='./public/images/right-carousel-arrow.svg'>"
})
```

I tried making option `draggable` to false. But it doesn't seem to do the work.

(EDIT):
The draggable options does work for mouse but when testing for mobile view, using touch sensor, it doesn't seem to work.